# How to add an image to the emulator gallery in android studio?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I am developing an image filter app. But can't really try it if i don't have any images.

I know that i can test it in the phone, but it's not the same, since I need the error messages and other stuff.

I just want to access an image from the AVD's gallery so that I can test my app.
How can I add one?

I am using Android Studio. I saw some examples on how to do it in Eclipse, but i am not using that.

So, how can I add an image to the emulator image gallery?

Comment: Have you tried using the web browser and saving it?

Comment: Copy it to the DCIM folder in your emulator?

Comment: `but it's not the same, i need the error messages and other stuff.`. What do you mean? You get all logs and exceptions and stacktraces and errors in your logcat if you use a real device connected with a usb cable to your development pc.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: If your path for android sdk is set , then you can simply use `adb push` command from command prompt.  e.g if you have image say wallpaper.jpg in D: drive the open command prompt, `cd ` to D drive then , `adb push wallpaper.jpg /sdcard/` .. make sure your emulator is on

Comment: How about using your emulator's browser to download random images?

Answer (score 158):

It's a very old question but I will answer this for future references.

To add any file to emulator just drag and drop the file.

The file will be copied to downloads folder of internal storage.

To access the file

**Go to settings**

**Click On Storage & USB**

**Click On Internal Storage**

**Click On Explore (at the end)**

and you got it in the downloads folder

now you will get notification to setup virtual SD card, follow the setup.
after the successful setup you will be able to see pictures in gallery.

Comment: Yes, this works, and _far_ more simply than the other answers present here.  `Drag + drop` is the answer.  No mucking around with device monitors, settings, tools apps, or mounted filesystems.  Just launch the virtual device, drag, and drop.

Comment: But nothings loads in gallery. when oi check from DeviceExplorer i can find the file in path but from emulator nothing shown.

Comment: If I could have up-voted this solution more than once I would have! This was such a simple solution and I was surprisingly unable to find it anywhere else online.

Comment: I don't see `Explore` option in my emulator

Comment: And this is why I use iPhone

Comment: I think this answer is now outdated

Comment: I don't see Storage & USB, I only see Storage and there's no Internal Storage in there.

Answer (score 64):

I'd like to complement Mithilesh Izardar's answer:

Indeed the best approach is simply to "Drag and Drop", which afterwards you can find the files in the emulator at `Settings → Storage → Internal Storage → Explore → Download` (API 25).
The problem for me was that after following these steps the pics weren't appearing neither in the "Gallery" nor in the "Downloads" (by simply clicking the "Downloads" icon).

The reason for this is because by default everything in the emulator has no permissions...so all you gotta do is give the "Gallery" storage permission: `Settings → Apps → Gallery → Permissions` (API 25)

Ps: If you just copied the pictures, the new ones won't show up right away. You should either restart the emulator, or remount the sdcard (at `Settings → Storage` unmount the sdcard by clicking the eject icon then remount it)

Comment: Finally! A solution that works. upvote for the last step. Without reboot or remount none of these would work

Comment: GREAT solution.

Answer (score 44):

How to import images into the gallery of an Android Virtual Device using Android Studio:
I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1 and a API 15 virtual device.

Warning:  This is manual intensive so it is not a good solution for a large number of images.

1. Create a virtual device using Android's Device Manager (AVD), Menu */Tools/Android/AVD Manager*.
2. Start this virtual device.
3. Start the Android Device *monitor*,  Menu */Tools/Android/Android Device Monitor.  In the *Devices* tab (upper left) you should see your device.  It should be *Online* (see  [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoOOR.png))
4. On the right window is the *File Explorer*.  Go there and select the */mnt/sdcard/Pictures* directory.  It should be highlighted (see  [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9JN6.png))
5. Add jpegs to this directory by clicking on the *Push a file onto the device* icon (the little phone icon I highlighted in the above screenshot.  You can add only one photo at a time, dadburnit.
6. Go to your device and run the *Dev Tools* app.
7. Scroll down and select *Media Provider.*
8. Click on the *Scan SD Card* button.  This should copy the images you added in step 5 to the gallery.  Go to the gallery and look, they should be there.

Comment: My Media Provider crashes when I click Scan SD Card...any hints?

Comment: My Media Provider crashes too. @Daniel any luck fixing it?

Comment: So does mine :( any joy anyone? @faridghar any luck?

Comment: To be honest, I fixed it, but now I can't remember how. Will keep trying to figure out what I did and get back to you.

Comment: Apparently it's a known bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62134

Comment: Great... Now you need to own all kind of devices to test your app

Comment: I tried this solution, it crashed. then @Boo 's solution, dev tools crashed again. Tried accessing pictures from folder, voila found them.

Comment: Tried several approaches listed on this SO with no success - I then stopped and restarted the emulator and there they are.  So if you try any approach, be sure to stop and restart emulator before evaluating success.

Comment: My Media Provide crashed too. But when I restarted the device I was able to see all the files I pushed.

Answer (score 21):

After trying to add an image via the Device Monitor or via drop, I could find it when exploring, but it was still not shown in the Gallery.

For me, it helped to eject the (virtual) sdcard from *Settings > Storage & USB* and reinserting it.

Comment: here is the video how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TmU6sRHI8w . it is not mine

Answer (score 18):

I went through the Android Device Monitor

1. Click on device
2. Select Android Device Monitor's File Explorer tab
3. Select Pictures folder  (path: data -> media -> 0 -> Pictures)
4. Click "Push folders on to device" icon
5. Select pic from computer and ok.

Answer (score 17):

**Copy a file to the emulator:**

Open emulator and File Explorer (Finder in Mac) side by side. Choose the file you want to copy then Drag and Drop the file onto the emulator. The selected file will be copied to the Downloads folder of the emulator.

**How to view files in Android Studio:**

Android Studio has **Device Explorer** to explore emulator content (Earlier we used to have DDMS, which is deprecated in Studio 3+). Goto View -> Tools Window -> Device File Explorer and you can see the explorer window. Goto Storage -> emulated -> 0 ->Download, if you don't see the file here, please restart the emulator and that's it.

**Note:** You don't see **Device Explorer** if you have opened a Flutter project.

You can also view the image files in Android Studio by double-clicking the file in the emulator.

[image: See image below]

Comment: If Dragging does not work just right click on the folder and upload.

Answer (score 15):

As of API 28 at least:

1. Open Settings app in emulator
2. Search for "Storage" select search result for it
3. Select Photos & Videos in Storage
4. Select Images
5. Drag an image onto the emulator, it won't immediately show up
6. From the AVD Manager in Android Studio, cold boot the emulator

The photos you've dragged in are now available.

Comment: cold booting the emulator is what makes this work :-)

Answer (score 9):

Workaround simple and quick. Upload file/photo on cloud (from outside the emulator) and download with browser on the emulator.

Comment: I like your approach

Comment: great, i just sent myself the file by gmail and downloaded it from emulator.

Comment: By far the easiest solution

Answer (score 6):

Try using Device File Explorer:

1. Start the Device
2. Navigate to View->Tool Windows->Device File Explorer to open the Device File Explorer
3. Click on sdcard and select the folder in which you want to save the file to.
4. Right-click on the folder and select upload to select the file from your computer.
5. Select the file and click ok to upload

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem too. I used this code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Using the `ADM`, add the images on the sdcard or anywhere.

And when you are in your vm and the selection screen shows up, browse using the top left dropdown seen in the image below.

[image: look at 'open from']

Answer (score 3):

Although you can have logat on a real device too, if you need to use an emulator try transferring the images through the Android Device Monitor, accessible from the toolbar in Android Studio (it's in eclipse too, of course).

Once you select the device from ADM, you can see the folders tree and copy things inside

Answer (score 2):

1. open emulator and image folder of your pc windows side by side. Drag and drop images to emulator.
2. download the images from web on your emulator.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

### How to add images into emulator ?

**Method-1**:

1. Drag and Drop images into emulator
2. Emulator > Settings > Storage > SDCARD > unmount then re-mount
3. Open Download app to see the images or from gallery access storage images.

Answer (score 1):

All of these seem to be outdated.  So I found a very quick simple solution.

1. Drag and drop the picture onto the emulator. It will look like nothing happens
2. Add more as desired.
3. Close the emulator using the tiny close button, or close the tab if you still have it in windowed mode.
4. Go to your device manager.  Click the vertical ... button on the far right of your device, and choose Cold Boot Now.  This makes it skip the save state. [image]
5. When it boots up, all your photos should appear in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered the question, this is to show how you can do it in the real device. Of course, you have to use the emulator if you have some reasons against using your real device.

Logs and exceptions will be displayed in the 'Run' tab in Android Studio.
I have worked on apps which have C++ and Java.

C++ logging:

```
__android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Logger", "C++-JNI");
```

Java logging:

```
Log.i("Logger", "Java");
```

These kind of logs show in the 'Run' tab and this should cover all your needs.

Follow the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app#RealDevice) to to set up your device for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

some how drag and drop doesn't work for me, but this worked.

go to Device explorer, right bottom , vertical tab generally.
in directory tree choose mnt\sdcard<destination Directory>, right click on it, select "Upload", then select desired files you want to upload.
[Device File explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh2Cs.png)

Answer (score 0):

drag and drop from File Explorer to the Android simulator works, the images will be placed under the download section.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).