# Image dragged to Android emulator does not show up in gallery

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I used to drag the image to Android emulator API 30 and the image would show up in emulator gallery. However with `Android 2021.1.1 Patch 2`, images dragged to the emulator does not show up in gallery or anywhere else. Android shows a message saying  that the image has been copied but it could not be seen in gallery. Here is the image of the android emulator:

[image]

Clicking open the gallery shows nothing inside after dropping the image. Here is the SD card configed for the emulator:

[image]

How to populate image to gallery on emulator in `Android 2021.1.1 Patch2`?

Comment: have you tried checking the sd card directory? It might go there

Comment: It may be. But on emulator I didn't find where is the SD card directory.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to upload files to Emulator:**

Copy the image(very important)

Android Studio has **Device Explorer** to explore emulator content (Earlier we used to have DDMS, which is deprecated in Studio 3+). Go to View -> Tools Window -> Device File Explorer and you can see the explorer window. Go to Storage -> emulated -> 0 ->Download. Here paste that photo

**Note:** You don't see **Device Explorer** if you have opened a Flutter project.

[image: See image below]

Comment: For some reason it shows up in Device File Explorer but in the device itself it does not

Comment: Did you check the `Files` app on the device? Nowadays they go there. From there, you need to upload it on to google photos

Comment: I ended up solving it. I don't remember exactly what I did but I think I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588124/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-emulator-gallery-in-android-studio) thread trying different things until it worked. I copied the image into several folders however until one actually showed up in the device.