Why does it stop when I search for emulator? How do I solve it?
I wanted to insert an image, so I tried downloading it in Chrome, but it froze.
After running Chrome on the emulator, when I go to a webpage or search, the computer freezes.
help me..
I just wanted to download an image from Chrome inside the emulator.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question seems appropriate for SuperUser.

You can try this way to copy instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/38736733/6478047 ?

I solved it using vulkan.  thanks !!!
